# Getting a "dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex" error when using a context in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trying to create a very simple application in kubernetes (using docker on windows 11) it is properly configured, but the thing is that when I create a context and then try to use it, I get the following error when I run commands.

> Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

When I switch again to the namespace docker-desktop, I am able to create resources again.

Comment: Did you check your firewall or antivirus settings? Do they allow port exposing etc?